# How to send notification from the web to Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to send a notification from my site to the users of my app, but it is not working. This is what I have now:

```
  async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken, title, description) {
    const message = {
      to: expoPushToken,
      sound: "default",
      title: title,
      body: description,
      badgecount: 1,
    };

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: message,
    }).then(function (response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
  }
```

I tried to do it with Axios, but with no luck. The original way that is explained on their using the `await fetch` method also doesn't work. I don't get a response at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#api) may help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check their [Push Notification Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#api) 
Sample code

`async function schedulePushNotification() { await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({ content: { title: "You've got mail! ", body: 'Here is the notification body', data: { data: 'goes here' }, }, trigger: { seconds: 2 }, }); }`